# The difference between the nonlocal and local conditions problems

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

In some of Boundary value problems involving ordinary differential equations,, subsidiary conditions are imposed locally. In some other cases, nonlocal conditions are imposed.

In this paper: [Existence and uniqueness of a classical solution to a functional-differential abstract nonlocal Cauchy problem](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijsa/1999/957201/abs/) Byszewski studied this form of functional-differential **nonlocal** problem:

> $(1)\left\{\begin{matrix}
>  u'(t)=f(t,u(t),u(a(t))),\:\:t\in I \\ 
>  u(t_0)+\sum_{k=1}^{p}c_ku(t_k)=x_0 
> \end{matrix}\right.$
>
> With $I:=[t_0,t_0+T], t_0<t_1<...<t_p\leq t_0+T, T>0$ and $f:I\times E^2\rightarrow E \:$ and $\:a:I\rightarrow I \:$are given functions satisfying some assumptions; $E$ is a Banach space with norm $\:\left \| . \right \|;  x_0\in E, c_k\neq 0 \:\:(k=1,...,p)\: p \in \mathbb N$.

And here, in the classical Robin problem: $$u''(t) + f(t,u(t),u'(t)) = 0$$

> With **local** conditions: $u(0)= 0$ and $u'(1) = 0.$

Or

> With **nonlocal** conditions: $u(0)= 0$ and $u(1) = u(\eta)\;\:\eta\in(0,1)$

My question is:

-When we say that the boundary conditions are **local** or **nonlocal**?

-In which situation we impose **local** or **nonlocal** conditions?

*Thank you!*